# write multi dimensional numpy array to many files

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing the following without using loops.

I have a numpy array with the shape `(i, x, y, z)`. Essentially I have `i` elements of the shape `(x, y, z)`.
I want to write each element to a separate file so that I have `i` files, each with the data from a single element.

In my case, each element is an image, but I'm sure a solution can be format agnostic.

I'm currently looping through each of the `i` elements and writing them out one at a time.

As `i` gets really large, this takes a progressively longer time. Is there a better way or a useful library which could make this more efficient?

******Update******

I tried the suggestion to use multiprocessing by using concurrent.futures both the thread pool and then also trying the process pool. It was simpler in the code but the time to complete was 4x slower.

`i` in this case is approximately 10000 while `x` and `y` are approximately 750

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html ?

Comment: 1) When you say you're looping over the files, do you mean that you have one loop over i, or four nested loops over i, x, y, and z? 2) How big is each file? That's going to affect the maximum speedup you'll get from avoiding loops.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very suitable for multiprocessing, as the different elements need to be processed separately and can be save to disk independantly.
Python has a usefull package for this, called `multiprocessing`, with a variety of pooling, processing, and other options.
Here's a simple (and comment-documented) example of usage:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np    


# This should be your existing function
def write_file(element):
    # write file
    pass


# You'll still be looping of course, but in parallel over batches. This is a helper function for looping over a "batch"
def write_list_of_files(elements_list):
    for element in elements_list:
        write_file(element)


# You're data goes here...
all_elements = np.ones((1000, 256, 256, 3))

num_procs = 10  # Depends on system limitations, number of cpu-cores, etc.
procs = [Process(target=write_list_of_files, args=[all_elements[k::num_procs, ...]]) for k in range(num_procs)]  # Each of these processes in the list is going to run the "write_list_of_files" function, but have separate inputs, due to the indexing trick of using "k::num_procs"...

for p in procs:
    p.start()  # Each process starts running independantly

for p in procs:
    p.join()  # assures the code won't continue until all are "joined" and done. Optional obviously...
    
print('All done!')  # This only runs onces all procs are done, due to "p.join"
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this now. I tried using a pool first but let me try this